# Django channel 2 routing issue when pushed to heroku

Tags: python, heroku, websocket, gunicorn, django-channels

I have a wsgi project with added asgi/channel component in it. When I run it in python3 manage.py runserver, I am able to get websocket connection when I use a websocket tester on it with ngrok.io. My ngrok.io then displays:

```
GET  /ws/                      101 Switching Protocols
```

but when i use heroku local or push it into their cloud, it says that '/ws/' not found:

```
9:12:04 PM web.1 |  [2019-12-20 21:12:04 -0800] [5123] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
9:12:04 PM web.1 |  [2019-12-20 21:12:04 -0800] [5123] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (5123)
9:12:04 PM web.1 |  [2019-12-20 21:12:04 -0800] [5123] [INFO] Using worker: sync
9:12:04 PM web.1 |  [2019-12-20 21:12:04 -0800] [5126] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 5126
9:12:10 PM web.1 |  Not Found: /ws/
```

Which looks like it's looking for the wsgi side of my server.(?) But my websocket is on the asgi side.

GET /ws/                       400 Bad Request

my requirements.txt consists of

```
Django==2.2.6
django-heroku==0.3.1
daphne==2.4.0
gunicorn==19.9.0
requests==2.22.0
channels==2.3.1
```

my routing.py has

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "websocket": URLRouter([
        path('ws/', backEndConsumer),
    ])
})
```

while my url.py has

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('webhook/', views.webhook, name='webhook'),
]
```

my settings.py is https://justpaste.it/78n46
Since the code isn't any different, then it is probably the difference in environment. My pip3 freeze has a lot of files, so I am not sure I can figure out which dependency is missing, if any. https://justpaste.it/3r5wd

Maybe I'm not supposed to use gunicorn and switch to daphne? but my current set up works fine with python3, why would it not work when I run it on heroku?

Comment: What's the content of your Procfile?

Comment: it is web: gunicorn APbackend.wsgi